# GRUB GNU Shows Up after reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: boot

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04.3 on a PC that had already Ubuntu installed.
But after I removed the installation media it didn't boot into Ubuntu instead it now shows the GRUB GNU. When I type exit it just prompts

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
> or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

Should I do something specific with my hard drive as Ubuntu creates new partitions every time I try to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure it says GRUP GNU?

Comment: I'm very sorry, of course it's GRUB, not GRUP

Comment: It sounds like you installed to the USB and not the hard drive. It happens.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? I've tried installing it from a USB stick and a SD card several times.

Comment: SD card is this a Ras Pi? I would say download a new ISO and verify it. Make a new live USB and install again.

Comment: I only tried a SD card as I didn't have a USB stick. After the installation with the SD card failed, I tried again with a new image and on USB, but with the same result.

Comment: This is not a raspberry pi it is a normal  PC with an Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G620 @ 2.60GHz × 2. Windows 7 was originally on it.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what exactly caused the problem, but for some reason Ubuntu created new partitions and failed to delete old ones every time it tries to install.

I found out about this because every time I tried to do a new install, different partitions were formatted. The number of partitions seemed to have increased with each installation. I also saw that when I entered the command "ls" in GRUB.

I fixed this by manually deleting all partitions and then starting a fresh install.